# grub configuration from systemrescuecd upgrade from 5 to 6

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, grub

I have a configuration that is working with SystemRescueCd v5, looks like this:

```
menuentry 'System Rescue Cd' {
  set isofile='/systemrescuecd.iso'
  loopback loop (hd3,gpt2)$isofile
  linux (loop)/isolinux/rescue64 isoloop=$isofile nouveau.blacklist=1 nomodeset
  initrd (loop)/isolinux/initram.igz
}
```

Now, based on the latest version it says here:
http://www.system-rescue-cd.org/manual/Installing_SystemRescueCd_on_the_disk/

Looks like this:

```
menuentry "SystemRescueCd (isoloop)" {
    load_video
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    search --no-floppy --label boot --set=root
    loopback loop /systemrescuecd.iso
    echo   'Loading kernel ...'
    linux  (loop)/sysresccd/boot/x86_64/vmlinuz img_label=boot img_loop=/systemrescuecd.iso archisobasedir=sysresccd copytoram setkmap=us
    echo   'Loading initramfs ...'
    initrd (loop)/sysresccd/boot/x86_64/sysresccd.img
}
```

Given, now I use the ISO on a different drive I tried to upgrade as:

```
menuentry "SystemRescueCd (isoloop)" {
    load_video
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
#    search --no-floppy --label boot --set=root
#    loopback loop /systemrescuecd.iso
set isofile='/systemrescuecd.iso'
loopback loop (hd3,gpt2)$isofile
    echo   'Loading kernel ...'
    linux  (loop)/sysresccd/boot/x86_64/vmlinuz img_label=boot img_loop=/systemrescuecd.iso archisobasedir=sysresccd copytoram setkmap=us
    echo   'Loading initramfs ...'
    initrd (loop)/sysresccd/boot/x86_64/sysresccd.img
}
```

It starts up with booting, but then it throws this error:
`Waiting 30 seconds for device /dev/disk/by-label/boot`

Do you know what it could be?
I just try to use the booting SystemRescueCd from a different drive, but the rest is the same...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
menuentry "System Rescue CD" {
    set gfxmode=auto
    set gfxpayload=keep
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod font
    insmod gfxterm
    insmod video
    insmod videotest
    terminal_output gfxterm
    set uuid="#UUID"
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root $uuid
    set iso="systemrescuecd-6.0.3.iso"
    loopback loop /$iso
    linux (loop)/sysresccd/boot/x86_64/vmlinuz scandelay=1 copytoram doxdetect archisobasedir=sysresccd img_label=#LABEL img_loop=/$iso
    initrd (loop)/sysresccd/boot/intel_ucode.img (loop)/sysresccd/boot/amd_ucode.img (loop)/sysresccd/boot/x86_64/sysresccd.img
}
```

this is based on the above solution, it was working, but the X.org was failing and it was setting english keymap, so i removed that and I added the `doxdetect` to work on any vga driver.

well you see #UUID and #LABEL, you can get you partation from `blkid`

then it works with startx

Answer (score 1):

I found a menu that works for me, so i paste it here and write down some comments (:

```
default=0
timeout=13

set gfxmode=auto
set gfxpayload=keep
insmod part_msdos
insmod part_gpt
insmod efi_gop
insmod efi_uga
insmod font
insmod gfxterm
insmod video
insmod videotest
terminal_output gfxterm
loadfont /grub/fonts/unicode.pf2

menuentry "Apagar" {
    halt
}

menu "SystemRescueCD 6.0.3 [64 Bits]" {
    set uuid="..."
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root $uuid
    set iso="systemrescuecd-6.0.3.iso"
    loopback loop /$iso
    linux (loop)/sysresccd/boot/x86_64/vmlinuz scandelay=1 setkmap=es copytoram dostartx archisobasedir=sysresccd img_label=... img_loop=/$iso
    initrd (loop)/sysresccd/boot/intel_ucode.img (loop)/sysresccd/boot/amd_ucode.img (loop)/sysresccd/boot/x86_64/sysresccd.img
}
```

On the line with `set uuid="..."`, instead of `...`, put the UUID of the partition where the ISO is located, it will be used as root.

On the parameter `img_label=...`, instead of `...`, put the LABEL of the partition where the ISO is located, it will be mounted prior to losetup, so ISO file can be located.

That was the trick for me, putting the LABEL of the 'other' partition where i have my ISO files, not the label of the partition where i have Grub2 installed.

Hope this helps you and others.

Note1: I must try deeply with other versions of SystemRescueCD, bu i suppose if it works with latest 6.0.3 it must work with any 6.x prior to 6.0.3 (but i did not tested).

Note2: The `dostartx` do not work at all, i must type `startx` everytime, but the `copytoram` and `setkmap=es` (for Spanish keyboard) works.

Comment: i accept this solution, although for me it is not working, because startx is not working, it says cannot run in framebuffer mode. please specify bus id, but it starts up at least...

Comment: another little typo is, that it should say menuentry instead of menu

Comment: and remove setkmap=es, as not everyone wants to use es keymap... :)

Comment: to find out the label and uuid, it is found out via the `blkid` command

Comment: for me the X driver was not working, I add a complete solution, but this is the best you solved it, thanks!